# Generic print function for S3 class

Tags: r, generics, r-package, r-s3

I have an S3 class, and I'm trying to work out how to set up a print function for it.

This part's good.

```
print.webglobe <- function(wg, ...){
  "it worked!"
}
```

But, if I run `devtools::check()` on it, I get the following ominous message:

```
checking S3 generic/method consistency ... WARNING
print:
  function(x, ...)
print.webglobe:
  function(wg, ...)
```

I tried adding the additional code:

```
print <- function(wg, ...){
  UseMethod("webglobe", wg)
}
```

But, with this present, `print.webglobe()` never seems to be accessed and my S3 class just prints as a list of some sort.

How can I set up this up correctly?

Comment: Change the `wg` to `x`. The formal arguments of a method have to match those of the generic. That's why the print isn't working the way you would expect.

Comment: @Thomas: That was it. Could you please post your comment as an answer instead?

Answer (score 2):

Change the `wg` to `x`. The formal arguments of a method have to match those of the generic because arguments from the generic call are passed, based upon name, to the method. That's why the `print()` isn't working the way you would expect because `wg` is being sent to the `wg` rather than the method's first argument.